# How to get data in drop-downlist using maatawebsite/excel version 3.1

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have the PHP version 7.3 and laravel version id >=5.5. I need to export templated data from database to excel. For this I have used **"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"**.
I have to display categories in `drop-down list` so that user can select from that when import.
Here I have attached the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elaAd.png) for same.

How can I achieve this using version 3.1?

**sample code**:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;
use App\Models\CategoryMaster;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class CompanyExport implements  WithEvents{

use Exportable;

protected $request;
protected $results;

function __construct($request){
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function collection()
{
    // store the results for later use
    $this->results = CategoryMaster::get();

    return $this->results;
}

public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        BeforeSheet::class => function(BeforeSheet $event) {
            
            $sheet = $event->sheet;
            $sheet->append(['name','category']);
            $cntCat = CategoryMaster::count();
            
            $income = CategoryMaster::where('level',1)->get();
                           

            $generateCell = function($accounts,$sheet,&$row) use(&$generateCell)
            {
                foreach ($accounts as $account) 
                {
                    $sheet->append([$account->name],'A'.$row++);
                    
                }
                return $sheet;
            };
            $row = 1;
            $sheet->append(['Income'],'A'.$row++);
            $sheet = $generateCell($income,$sheet,$row);
    
        },
         AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event){
             $sheet = $event->sheet;
            $objValidation = $sheet->getCell('A2')->getDataValidation();
            $objValidation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
            $objValidation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
            $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
            $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
            $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
            $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
            $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
            $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
            $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
            $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
            $options = [
                'option 1',
                'option 2',
                'option 3',
            ];
            $objValidation->setFormula1(sprintf('"%s"',implode(',',$options)));
            for ($i = 3; $i <= 200; $i++) {
                $sheet->getCell("C{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $objValidation);
            }
         }
     ];
  }
}
```

Comment: [How to make a Dropdown list (version 3.1)? #2229](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2229) check it out

Comment: I tried this solution. but not getting result